# Am I assigning values to the array incorrectly?

Tags: c++

I have a code that is supposed to take a file with n lines, each with p doubles, and add each double to a 2d array. For some reason when I try to print the array it shows every other row being zeroed out. What am I doing wrong?

The text file would look like this

```
3.0 5.0 9.0 1.0
7.0 10.0 2.0 6.0
4.0 8.0 11.0 12.0
20.0 19.0 15.0 13.0
29.0 24.0 17.0 21.0
```

Here is my code

```
fileInStream.open(input);

cellArr = new double[rows * cols];

int i, j = 0;

while (getline(fileInStream, line)){
  stringstream ss(line);
  while (ss >> cell){
    *(cellArr + i * cols + j) = stod(cell);
    j++;
  }      
  i++;
}

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
    cout << *(cellArr + i * cols + j) << " ";
  }
  cout << endl;
}
```

My output looks like this

```
3 5 9 1 
0 0 0 0 
7 10 2 6 
0 0 0 0 
4 8 11 12
```

Comment: Tip: In C++ use `std::vector` and stay far, far away from `new[]`.

Comment: `*(cellArr + i * cols + j) = stod(cell)`? Please don't. If you're using an array, just use it normally, like `cellArr[i * cols + j]`. It makes it *vastly* easier to follow what you're doing.

Comment: `i` is unitialized, yielding undefined behavior.

Comment: Step 1: print the values when you read them to verify that the input is what you assume.

Comment: @Chris does int i, j = 0 not initialize I?

Comment: @molbdnilo when I did that I got a seg fault.

Comment: @Coder99 It only initializaes `j`. Every variable need its own initializer. A segfault when you modify something trivial is a very solid indication of undefined behaviour somewhere.

Comment: @Coder99 Use `std::vector` instead of using `new[]` and `delete[]`.

Comment: `int i=0, j=0;` And you never reset `j` on each row advance either.

Comment: @Coder99  please learn how to use a debugger: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems

Comment: Do not edit your question to correct your code after answer's suggestions. Rollbacked.

Answer (score 0):

You've made a few basic logic mistakes.  `i` is unitialized, yielding undefined behavior. Also, `j` is never reset. It should reset to `0` at the beginning of each row.

As it is, if you run this for a simple 2x2 array, assuming `i` is `0` to start, we have:

```
i = 0, j = 0 -> cellArr[i * cols + j] -> cellArr[0]
i = 0, j = 1 -> cellArr[i * cols + j] -> cellArr[1]
i = 1, j = 2 -> cellArr[i * cols + j] -> cellArr[4]
i = 1, j = 3 -> cellArr[i * cols + j] -> cellArr[5]
```

Code I used to test, modified from your code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int rows = 2;
    int cols = 2;

    auto cellArr = new double[rows * cols];

    int i = 0;
    string line;

    while (getline(cin, line)) {
       double cell;
       int j = 0;
       stringstream ss(line);

       while (ss >> cell) {
          cellArr[i * cols + j] = cell;
          j++;
       }

       i++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            cout << cellArr[i * cols + j] << " ";
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

We can use `for` loops to clean this up a bit.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int rows = 2;
    int cols = 2;

    auto cellArr = make_unique<double[]>(rows * cols);

    int i = 0;

    string line;

    for (int i = 0; i < rows && getline(cin, line); ++i) {
       stringstream ss(line);
       for (int j = 0; j < cols && ss >> cellArr[i * rows + j]; ++j);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            cout << cellArr[i * cols + j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```